# Owncloud 8 change Hashtype

Tags: php, md5, owncloud

I want to change the Hashtype in my Owncloud 8 installation from SHA1SUM to MD5. Which files have to be edited?

Answer (score 0):

Editing the core of ownCloud is not considered as a good practice by the developers. As "AnybodyElse" user writes on https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=9250,

> "Don't patch core - write a custom user backend. Check the source of the user_ldap application."

If you insist on doing so and are aware of the dangers of doing so, the autor of the above linked HOWTO, "dragnovich", points to the file `owncloud/lib/user/database.php`. If you are not aware of the dangers of patching ownCloud core this way, I would not recommend you to attempt it and use it on production environment.